# Copy-paste in textarea doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, textarea, copy-paste

I have a little mystery.

When you have a `div { display: none; }` rule in your css, and a `textarea` on the page, it is impossible to copy and paste in the `textarea` in a Chrome browser.

What's going on?

### http://pastehtml.com/view/ax3tuefz3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in WebKit.

I've filed a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86025

Answer (score 2):

I tried and yes the paste seems to be broken in your example.

There were some bugs reported on chrome buglist:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60057

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61784

But they are long closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is`display:none;` is applying to all your `div`s.

I gave your button a `class`:

`<div id="login" class="login">`

And made sure the `display:none;` only applied to it

```
div.login {
    display: none;
}
```

Then I hid your form off the top

`$('#view_form').hide();`

Works now: http://jsbin.com/umugi5/3/

Comment: It seems that the `div { display: none; }` css rule is breaking copy-paste in the textarea. I've filed a bug report (link in question). Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: No problem.  Hope that answered the question.